# CoinDaemon fails to bind address

Tags: bind

When I run my coin daemon on my computer, I get this error:

> 20: 56: 42.149854 ERROR Exception: TcpListener :: TcpListener, bind failed, result = 98, Address already in use

although when running the same on the Amazon server it works fine. I do not even know what to do to help someone is not difficult.

Comment: that means an application on your computer is already using the port that your TcpListener is trying to bind to.

Comment: "Address already in use" means the address is already in use. Find out what listens to that address, close it and retry.

Comment: Not the best worded question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a Linux like OS, try something like:

`netstat -tulpn`

It will show you what application is using what port. Identify the app that's using the port you want and stop it.